# Xcode 7 Beta 4 - Cannot find storyboard every 2nd time I run the project

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

It might be a beta-prerelease-bug in Xcode, but did anyone other experience the same thing?

I clean the project - Run it - Everything's fine.

Then I stop the project - Run it again - just a black screen and this log:

```
2015-08-03 23:22:30.743 XXXXXXX[12221:2892479] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard' in bundle NSBundle </private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/920917A0-44DF-4B5F-91A8-BB669DDF5F0D/XXXXXXXX.app> (loaded)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1822542d8 0x193f200e4 0x18728e810 0x186f59edc 0x186f59074 0x186f5770c 0x18aa893c8 0x18220c27c 0x18220b384 0x1822099a8 0x1821352d4 0x186d383d0 0x186d32f40 0x1001ac504 0x1945caa08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Then I can clean it and do the same thing all over...

And yes, the storyboard is added correctly. It's also added correctly in the info.plist and I have also tried to remove it and add it again. With the same result.

**UPDATE I**

Same thing happens in the latest Xcode Beta 5.

**UPDATE II**

This is the log from the second time I ran it in a simulator.

```
2015-08-10 12:09:19.552 XXXXX[32346:418981] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard' in bundle NSBundle </Users/johndoe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9685DA45-378D-48AC-BF8C-0DD2EF24C9B3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/17882AD9-E024-41A1-9E9B-9DC2C2845EA5/XXXXX.app> (loaded)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001116e69b5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000112927deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   UIKit                               0x000000010f4564f7 -[UIStoryboard name] + 0
    3   UIKit                               0x000000010ed9b310 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 58
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010ed9b664 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 260
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010ed99fc9 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1383
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010ed97390 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    7   FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011347b7ac -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
    8   FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011347bb1a -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111612b21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111608a4c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111607f03 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111607918 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010ed96d2d -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010ed9b99e UIApplicationMain + 171
    15  Teazr                               0x000000010e78912f main + 111
    16  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000112ecc92d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Could it be some kind of Facebook bug in the new SDK?

Comment: Also, try resetting the simulator. There have been bugs in the past where files in the generated app bundle were not all copied across on a build and run. Maybe something similar going on here.

Comment: @RobGlassey it happens in the simulator + the devices.

Comment: aaand a reset didn't help

Comment: The bug is happening when `[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName];` or something similar is called. It has nothing to do with the Facebook SDK.

Comment: Did you resolve this?  It just started happening to me today

Comment: Take a look at my answer @iPhoneGuy :)

Comment: I don't see an answer -- just comments that the answers suggested to you are not working?

Comment: Ah sorry @iPhoneGuy thought it was another issue. This bug was gone after i upgraded XCode to the latest working non-beta-version from App Store.

Comment: I am on Xcode 7.0.1 (7A1001) from the App Store and the problem just reared its ugly head.

Comment: I closed XCode and the simulator completely, reopened and all is good.

Comment: It's a Beta, as in not fully vetted for production yet. This error is most likely something they will be addressing before the final version.

Answer (score 1):

Update Xcode to stable version.

Comment: Please note that XCode 7 (beta) is outdated - we should be running XCode 8.1 now.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the crash log, it's apparent that Xcode can't find `MainStoryboard.storyboard` in the App's Bundle. Here are steps I would recommend you take so that the problem ceases.

---

## 1: Make sure the storyboard actually exists.

This involves opening Finder, going to the project's directory, and confirming that `MainStoryboard.storyboard` is, in fact, in the project's folder, it exists, and that it is readable/writable.

**If the storyboard doesn't exist, skip to step 3. Otherwise...**

---

## 2: Remove the reference to `MainStoryboard.storyboard` from within the Xcode project.

On the file list to the left, click on `MainStoryboard.storyboard` to select it. Afterwards, hit [Command] + [Delete].

On the alert box asking you whether you want to move the file to the Trash or simply Remove Reference, click **Remove Reference**.

---

## 3: Add the Storyboard back in.

Bring up the dialog to add the storyboard back to the project like so:

`File` -> `Add Files to Project...`

Navigate to the project's folder and add `MainStoryboard.storyboard` back in.

---

## 4: Tidy up the project, build, and run again.

Simply clean the project, build it, and try running it again. **Twice.**

---

## 5: Re-install Xcode.

You heard me right. Delete Xcode, **and all files it has in the Library**, off of your Mac and install it again. This issue might be caused by a screwed-up install, and so you might need to uninstall it and install it again.

---

## A more technical explanation:

The code cannot find `MainStoryboard.storyboard`, as it appears not to exist in the App's Bundle. To those uneducated about the bundle, it is also known as the "binary." The Bundle is where developers put resources that the app needs to access locally. On build, Xcode (should) put(s) all files that are in the Bundle and makes it a Bundle.

Removing the reference and re-adding it back in should get it to always add it to the bundle, not just on every second run.

If `MainStoryboard.storyboard` is not readable, or it is not writable, Xcode will not include it in the Bundle.

Why it would only work 50% of the time is weird to me, as Xcode 6 runs every time. Making a brand-new project and running it shouldn't cause errors in the compiler, as every new project is created from a template.

If Xcode isn't executing the code that Apple's Developers put in a template (such as SpriteKit's default "Hello world!" message), then there's something wrong with Xcode. Un-install it and install it again.

To figure out why this problem occurs, more information is needed. Maybe we could show this to Apple and they might be able to fix this information by Xcode 7 GM!

Comment: @SimonDegn Well, I don't quite know then.